# Error when using GridLayout class in kivy for python window

Tags: python, kivy, window, kivy-language

Hello I'm learning kivy on python, window 11

Whenever I use GridLayout in "pnn.kv" file, I have this error "AssertionError"

For my code: I'm learning from this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS3b70pLYEU&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kSJVMyYeOQ8CXJ3z1k7gHn&index=8"

Written version from the tutorial:
"main.py" file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Layout(Widget):
    pass


class PnnApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PnnApp().run()
```

"pnn.kv" file:

```
<Layout>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "First Name: "
            TextInput:
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Last Name: "
            TextInput:
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Phone number: "
            TextInput:
                multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Login"
```

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your class name. There is already a `Layout` class in Kivy. Try changing `Layout` to something else (maybe `MyLayout`) everywhere in your code and `kv`.

Comment: John... you are a champ, thank you so much, I thought there was an issue with GridLayout since when I wrote this in kv '''<Layout > /n  Label:  /n text: "testing" ``` and it worked so I got stuck